# OAuthException Facebook while retrieving LIKES

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook graph APIs from a Web application, PHP SDK.
Since yesterday, I'm getting a lot of errors on this call:

$temp_ar = $facebook->api('/me/music?limit=200&offset=0');

The call has always worked well before, and for some users, still works. For some of the users, it doesn't work anymore ... here are some debug details:

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
    [result:protected] => Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => An unknown error has occurred.
                    [type] => OAuthException
                    [code] => 1
                )

        )

[message:protected] => An unknown error has occurred.
    [string:Exception:private] =>
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /home/..../base_facebook.php
    [line:protected] => 1325
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/....base_facebook.php
                    [line] => 896
                    [function] => throwAPIException
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [error] => Array
                                        (
                                            [message] => An unknown error has occurred.
                                            [type] => OAuthException
                                            [code] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [function] => _graph
                    [class] => BaseFacebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /me/music?limit=200&offset=0
                        )

                )
```

Comment: If it started yesterday I would suggest filing a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: it seems it is a bug
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251759635025024/
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was definitely a Facebook bug and it has been fixed today
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251759635025024/